ComponentName does not belong to sessionPackageName
Since updating Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) to 8.6.0 and launching an Android 13 device in the Android Studio emulator, I'm seeing this:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.myapp.android, PID: 1906
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.oldapp.service.DownloadService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ComponentName does not belong to sessionPackageName. sessionPackageName = io.myapp.android, ComponentName pkg = com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4498)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleCreateService(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ComponentName does not belong to sessionPackageName. sessionPackageName = io.myapp.android, ComponentName pkg = com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3015)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
    at android.media.session.ISession$Stub$Proxy.setMediaButtonReceiver(ISession.java:466)
    at android.media.session.MediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(MediaSession.java:289)
    at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21.setMediaButtonReceiver(MediaSessionCompat.java:3965)
    at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:588)
    at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:539)
    at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:503)
    at com.oldapp.util.compat.RemoteControlClientLP.register(RemoteControlClientLP.java:95)
    at com.oldapp.service.DownloadService.onCreate(DownloadService.java:301)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4485)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleCreateService(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2161) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.media.MediaButtonReceiverHolder.create(MediaButtonReceiverHolder.java:125)
    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord$SessionStub.setMediaButtonReceiver(MediaSessionRecord.java:958)
    at android.media.session.ISession$Stub.onTransact(ISession.java:251)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1280)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)

RemoteControlClientLP.java:95 is:
mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(downloadService, "MediaSession", null, mediaPendingIntent);

I have noticed a number of changes in how AGP creates a namespace from the AndroidManifest.xml and I also note above the ComponentName is not actually specified. I tried with a fully qualified name, but the same issue occurred.
The problem doesn't appear to occur in Android 12 or 14. Maybe it's related to the setup of the emulator? I'm not sure why we're getting a message from YouTube.
Dependencies
I've checked my dependencies and can see the issue begins when mediarouter:1.2.5 is used - 1.2.4 doesn't have the issue. mediarouter:1.2.5 updates its dependency on media to media:1.4.1. I think this change is where the error message is coming from.
Am I setting up the MediaSessionCompat correctly?
